# What is Vim's feature name for this: # vim:sw=4:ts=4:et:

Tags: vim

Even after 20 years with Vim, I keep forgetting name for the Vim feature where the editor picks up config statements from a comment at the beginning (or I think end) of a file:

```
# vim:sw=4:ts=4:et:
```

Thanks for a reminder!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's called modeline

```
:he modeline
```

> If you start editing a new file, and the 'modeline' option is on, a
>   number of lines at the beginning and end of the file are checked for 
>   modelines. There are two forms of modelines.

```
  The first form:   [text]{white}{vi:|vim:|ex:}[white]{options}

 [text]         any text or empty
 {white}        at least one blank character (<Space> or <Tab>)
 {vi:|vim:|ex:} the string "vi:", "vim:" or "ex:"
 [white]        optional white space
 {options}      a list of option settings, separated with white space or ':',
                where each part between ':' is the argument for a ":set"
                command (can be empty)
```

Add this to $MYVIMRC:

```
setglobal modeline
```

Comment: I wonder why my format does not work and this does: # vim:set sw=4 ts=4 et:

Comment: Try `:verbose set modeline modelines`; Also, read `:he ``modeline``` for background info & hints

Comment: Works! Actually I had extra colon in the beginning --- # :vim:xxxxxxx:

Answer (score 5):

It's called modeline. In help it can be found by grepping

```
helpgrep # vim
```

If you wish to check whether modeline are active, do *set modeline?* (if the are it will say *modeline*, otherwise *nomodeline*)

To turn them off for certain, add this in your vimrc

```
:set modelines=0 "number of modelines vim parses
:set nomodeline "turn off parsing
```

Answer (score 1):

`:h 'ts` (i.e. `:help 'tabstop'`) will bring up a detailed explanation of how to use `et`, `ts`, and `sw` as well as giving a pointer to `modeline` (`modeline` is the option that is in question).